# Using Google Sign Out at different page

Tags: javascript

I used the code below for Google sign in. It's working on the same page but I can't sign out the user at another page.

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        auth2.disconnect();
      console.log('User signed out.');
      document.location.href = "REDIRECT LINK";
    });
  }
</script>
```

How can I use the signOut() on another page?

Comment: I think if you re-use the sign-in-button at another site, it'll automatically will be shown as sign-out once the user is logged in

Comment: The text on the button becomes "Signed in"

Comment: And if your hide the button e.g. with `display: none` and show the signout-link instead